# Sólo 3 tipos de carácteres en un input

Tags: javascript, c#

Tengo un input, se pueden ingresar hasta 25 caracteres, sin embargo, solo los valores "-", "#" y "?" pueden ser aceptados, ya que con él se puede generar la máscara que se usaría en otros input, ¿hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Parte del código que he estado tratando de usar, pero no me realiza la función que quiero:

```
var out = ''; var filtro = '#-?'; 
for (var i = 0; i < data.Dato.length; i++) 
{ 
    if (filtro.indexOf(string.charAt(i)) != -1) 
        out += string.charAt(i); 
}
```

Comment: Usa [expresiones regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Ya lo intenté y nada, porqué laa expresiones regulares están dadas para un patrón. Aquí, por medio de esa caja de texto es donde el patrón se debe generar. La expresión regular espera una forma definitiva, este input puede recibir cualquier clase de patrón.

Comment: Estoy seguro que se podría resolver con una expresión regular. Cc. @Mariano

Comment: @Broodwing009, por qué etiquetaste como [tag:c#]??? Es en una página web? Por favor, intentá dar información más certera al hacer una pregunta

Comment: @Mariano ¿es decir que al mencionarte con el @ no te llega la notificación? Mi intención era esa, mencionarte para que vieras la pregunta y talvés dar una respuesta usando [tag:regex] ;)

Comment: @Flxtr no, no llega. Está en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/127, sólo al autor, otros que comentaron, editores, mods que cerraron o quien cerró con martillo, y quien ofrece una recompensa... Me di cuenta de la intención, gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Igualmente podrías utilizar regex y validar si la tecla presionada corresponde a los caracteres permitidos

```js
$('#test').keydown(function(e) {
  var rgx = /^[#?-]*$/;
  if( ! rgx.test(e.key)) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" placeholder="Only #-?" />
```

Comment: El regex está perfecto... El evento keydown es un poco cuestionable

Comment: Te agradezco hombre, que te dire, ya estaba cansado de lidear con ese codigo y fue lo primero que me vino a la mente...

Answer (score 0):

Al final pude conseguirlo, dejo esto para cualquiera que lo desee ver:

```
jq.find('#txtFormato').on('keypress', function (e) {
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    var tecla = String.fromCharCode(key).toLowerCase();
    var letras = "#?-";
    especiales = "8-37-39-46"; 

    tecla_especial = false
    for (var i in especiales) {
        if (key == especiales[i]) {
            tecla_especial = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (letras.indexOf(tecla) == -1 && !tecla_especial) {
        //console.log('El Formato del Dato solo puede contener los siguientes carateres: "#", "?", "-"');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Tu codigo es vulnerable en el sentido de que si el usuario copia y pega con el ratón tu script no se ejecutará, es mejor usar el evento "input".

Comment: ... además, ese bucle lo único que hace es recorrer caracter por caracter. Te recomiendo que leas sobre arrays y cómo recorrer los elementos